# javascript fetching and a variable from the url

Tags: javascript, window.location

I have the following url

http://www.domain.co.uk/example/#project-471-1747

The end bit #project-471-1747 changes every time a project is saved.

I pretty sure using window.location this can be pulled but what I am struggling to do is find out how to pull and display the full url when a button is clicked.

I'm sure this must be pretty simple to do but It seems to be eluding me!

Comment: you can use `location.href`

Comment: You could use `window.location.hash` it will return **#project-471-1747** or you can use `window.location.hash.replace('#','');` and that will return **project-471-1747** For the full URL `window.location.href` => **www.domain.co.uk/example/#project-471-1747** To find out more open your browser console and paste `window.location` into it. You can see all the window.location properties in the return.

Comment: It's unclear what you want. If you want the full URL, `String(location)` will give it to you as a string. If you just want the `#project-471-1747` part, that's `location.hash`.

Answer (score 1):

Your button markup can be something like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Display URL" onclick="urlDisplay()">
```

What this does is, on click of the button, it calls a function called `urlDisplay()`. You can have something like this in that function to show the full URL:

```
console.log(window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname);
```

Of course, you might not want to use console.log. You can choose to append it to some part of your markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = location.href;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

The above works and does what I need but is there a way to make this auto update every 2 seconds? e.g. so the user does not need to click "try me".

Comment: `setInterval(myFunction,2000);`

Comment: Cheers. where should I add the above?

Comment: Add it after the line containing closing brace of function myFunction.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
var path = window.location.hash;
```